# C++/CLI String Conversions

Tags: string, visual-c++, c++-cli, interop, stdstring

I found this really nice piece of code that converts a string to a `System:String^` as in:

```
System::String^ rtn = gcnew String(move.c_str());  // 'move' here is the string
```

I'm passing rtn back to a C# program. Anyways, inside the function where this code exists, I'm passing in a `System::String^`. I also found some code to convert a `System:String^` to a string using the following code:

```
pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wch = PtrToStringChars(cmd);  // 'cmd' here is the System:String          
size_t convertedChars = 0;
size_t  sizeInBytes = ((cmd->Length + 1) * 2);
errno_t err = 0;
char *ch = (char *)malloc(sizeInBytes);

err = wcstombs_s(&convertedChars,ch, sizeInBytes,wch, sizeInBytes);
```

Now I can use 'ch' as a string.

This, however, seems to be alot more work than converting the other way using the `gcnew`. So, at last my question is, is there something out there that will convert a `System::String^` to string using a similar fashion as with the gcnew way?

Comment: They make you do more work to intentionally do something nasty like that.  At least convert to utf8 if you have to, UTF8Encoding::GetBytes().

Answer (score 10):

Use VC++'s marshaling library: [Overview of Marshaling in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx)

```
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>

// given System::String^ mstr
std::string nstr = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(mstr);
```

Comment: Holy crap, thats sweet. Thanks Ill give it a go.

Comment: How about clean up. As per link "Marshaling requires a context only when you marshal from managed to native data types and the native type you are converting to does not have a destructor for automatic clean up." 

Say this method is invoked from native code, will it be cleaned?

      std::string getItem() {
            String^ result = "Some val";
            result += ".";
            return msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(result);
      }

Comment: @harsha : `std::string` has a destructor that frees its internal allocations, so that code is perfectly safe.

Answer (score 0):

this could be useful:

```
wchar_t *str = "Hi StackOverflow"; //native
String^ mstr= Marshal::PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr)str); // native to safe managed
wchar_t* A=( wchar_t* )Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(mstr).ToPointer(); // return back to native
```

don't forget `using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;`

Comment: Because this method allocates the unmanaged memory required for a string, always free the memory by calling FreeHGlobal.