# Can you use C++ libraries natively in a C++/CLI WinForms application?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++

You can create a VC++ Windows Forms project that runs on the CLR, which is essentially a .NET app written in C++. Can you use unmanaged C++ libraries directly from such a project? Does that mean that the library must compile and run under .NET? Or must you write [CLR wrapper classes](http://www.multicoreconsulting.co.uk/blog/c-snippets/how-to-call-unmanaged-cplusplus-from-csharp/) for such libraries and only those will be usable from the CLR app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Here are some guides. Mixing CLI/C++ and native code. You don't need a wrapper to use them in CLI/C++. In fact, you use CLI/C++ and native code to create a wrapper.

http://www.technical-recipes.com/2012/mixing-managed-and-native-types-in-c-cli/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35041/Mixing-NET-and-native-code

If you are actually trying to make a wrapper to use in C#, it should look something like this:

```
#include "NativeClass.h"

public ref class NativeClassWrapper {
    NativeClass* m_nativeClass;

public:
    NativeClassWrapper() { m_nativeClass = new NativeClass(); }
    ~NativeClassWrapper() { delete m_nativeClass; }
    void Method() {
        m_nativeClass->Method();
    }

protected:
    // an explicit Finalize() method—as a failsafe
    !NativeClassWrapper() { delete m_nativeClass; }
};
```

Refer to [C++/CLI wrapper for native C++ to use as reference in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223186/c-cli-wrapper-for-native-c-to-use-as-reference-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Yes, that's actually how you make wrappers. :]

Comment: This is how to create a wrapper, but you don't need to if you are using it in C++. If you want to bring it to C#, then yes, this is what you need. I noticed you tagged C#, so maybe that's what you want to do.

Comment: Better idea: Use a working smart pointer such as [this one I wrote](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1695/2150) instead of duplicating the memory cleanup code in each wrapper class.  For example, this answer has a memory leak.

Comment: @Geotarget: The above code didn't include a finalizer, so if you forget to call `Dispose()` it will leak.  Or if you call `Dispose()` more than once (yes, that's legal in .NET) bad things will happen.  Just replace `NativeClass* m_nativeClass;` with `clr_scoped_ptr<NativeClass> m_nativeClass;` and the compiler will then correctly generate the destructor and finalizer for you.

Comment: @Geotarget and BenVoigt I would personally stick to the simple method of creating wrappers until you get a better grip on the subject, but bookmark Bens answer for when you want to optimize your solution. This is the basics of creating a wrapper. But yes, those are the steps you need. Create a new CLI/C++ project and include the library and compile it as a DLL. Then import the DLL and copy the original library to your new C# project.

Comment: @Geotarget I just added the finalizer.

Comment: @Corylulu: Now bad things (double-delete) happen if you do call `Dispose`.  Why not use a solution that already works?

Comment: @Corylulu - I used a modified version of yours. Thanks again!!

Comment: @Corylulu Is it possible to create an unmanaged **.CPP** file without a library? I'm used to unmanaged C++, so my solution was a library (unmanaged) with some code to update the UI as needed. **Is this possible?** Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using a smart pointer library makes it much simpler to manage allocation of native (not garbage collected) objects, which is surprisingly difficult in the presence of exceptions, multiple calls to `Dispose()`, forgetting to call `Dispose()`, etc.

Here's Dr_Asik's example, rewritten to use [a smart pointer I wrote](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1695/2150):

```
#include "clr_scoped_ptr.h"
#include "NativeClass.h"

public ref class NativeClassWrapper {
    clr_scoped_ptr<NativeClass> m_nativeClass;

public:
    NativeClassWrapper() m_nativeClass(new NativeClass()) {}
    // auto-generated destructor is correct
    // auto-generated finalizer is correct

    void Method() {
        m_nativeClass->Method();
    }
};
```

For string conversions, use the `marshal_as` class Microsoft provided for the purpose.  Check out ildjarn's answer here: [C++/CLI String Conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6179487/103167)

Comment: Thanks for your well informed answer, Ben, I'm accepting it until someone comes up with a better answer. You seem to be a C++ pro judging by your SO rep on the matter (gold C++ badge, how many people have those?!) so I trust that you know exactly what you're talking about here. Constrast that with myself, a beginner. Well.. someday!

Comment: @Geotarget: SO rep and badges aren't the most reliable indicator, but I like to think I give good answers.  Keep practicing and you'll develop expertise as well.

Comment: Can you tell me a bit about converting C# data types to C++ and back? Just the basics for strings and ints/doubles. I've got some reference code here for strings: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35041/Mixing-NET-and-native-code but everything is still pretty flaky.