# How to convert a System::String to char* and use it with fopen?

Tags: file, crash, c++-cli

I wanna convert a System::String to char* as in order to open a file with `fopen` and then read it. I've tried with `(char *)System::Convert::ToChar`and it compiles fine but when I run the app it crashes. Here is the code:

```
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) //Convertir 
    {
        FILE * fichero = fopen((char*)Convert::ToChar(openFileDialog1->FileName), "r");
        if(fichero)
        {
```

But that crashes the app, so how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

To get a string pointer usable by `fopen()`, you should use the `marshal_as` template function.

You can obtain a `const char *` thusly:

```
#include <msclr\marshal.h>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
        std::string fileName = marshal_as<std::string>(openFileDialog1->FileName);
        FILE * fichero = fopen(fileName.c_str(), "r");
        if(fichero)
        {
```

**However**, do you *really* want to convert the string to narrow characters, therefore losing wide-character compatibility? No, you don't. You should actually use `_wfopen`, and `marshal_as<std::wstring>` (to get a `wchar_t` pointer) instead:

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <msclr\marshal.h>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
        std::wstring fileName = marshal_as<std::wstring>(openFileDialog1->FileName);
        FILE * fichero = _wfopen(fileName.c_str(), L"r");
        if(fichero)
        {
```

This is the correct code you should be using.

---

**Note:** To actually get a non-const `char*`, or if you only have Visual 2005, you should use `Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi` or `Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni` instead (don't forget the `Marshal::FreeHGlobal` when you're done with it) and cast the IntPtr into a `char*`/`wchar_t*` (probably via its `ToPointer` method).

Comment: Indeed, .NET uses the Unicode character set and the Windows file system (NTFS) does, too.

Comment: No, don't use these functions in C++/CLI.  Use the type-safe `marshal_as` template.  See linked question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179451/c-cli-string-conversions

Comment: @BenVoigt Sorry, I forgot not everyone is constrained to VS2005. I edited my answer.

Comment: @Medinoc: Even in VS2005, `marshal_as` should be used.  It's a pure header implementation, and can easily be dropped in.  The `Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi` and friends really suck because the return value is not a valid `HGLOBAL`.

Comment: Oh yeah, the "GMEM_FIXED = pointer" problem. In fact, I even just ILDASM'd the method, and noticed it actually uses `LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED)`.